# Running executables through Windows CMD without specifying entire path

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I am trying to open Windows System32 executables through the Windows Command Prompt (CMD) interface. For the purposes of simplicity, suppose we want to open the Calculator app. In the System32 directory, the application is called "calc.exe"

I do not want to specify C:\WINDOWS\System32\calc.exe each and every-time to run it.

Based on previous questions posted on SU, my understanding is that I change the PATH variable to the directory containing the calc.exe which in this case is C:\WINDOWS\System32. Thereafter, running the .exe should not require the full path.

After setting my path variable under advanced settings, it still doesnt seem to work. Is there anything else I need to try?

The solutions quoted in older duplicates dont seem to work for this specific scenario. I would have liked to comment on one of the answers for this case but I need 50 rep points to do so.

Comment: Please include the output of `echo %path%`

Comment: Did you log out and log back in? If you set the `PATH` variable through the GUI, you might not see the effect until you log out/in ..

Comment: there are system environmental variables and user environmental variables. easiest way to check if your path variables changed is to exit out of command prompt, run cmd, and type path to see what your path equals.

Comment: Huh? By default the Windows `Path` already includes `C:\WINDOWS\System32`. You don't need to do anything. Please explain exactly how you changed your `Path` as you have likely broken it.

Comment: @txtechhelp Thanks logging out an back in worked.